# How to setup NLog to create hourly log files on Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nlog

I use library [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/)
that write log app on Xamarin Forms.
My file log write log by hours.

***Example***: At 15 o'clock, a file log namefile_15.txt will be created.
When write log on file namefile_15.txt, until 16 o'clock, a file log namefile_16.txt will be created. File log namefile_15.txt is deleted log content and present log of file namefile_16.txt is written on file log namefile_15.txt.

Is it bug of `NLog`?

This is code use `Nlog` of me.

```
    public NLoggerFactory(string folderLog, string version)
    {
        // Format file
        const string dateTimeFormat = "yyyyMMdd.HH";
        var fileName = $"Log_v{version}";

        // Create targets
        // File target
        var fileTarget = new FileTarget
        {
            Name = "FileTarget",
            FileName = Path.Combine(folderLog, $"{fileName}.{DateTime.Now.ToString(dateTimeFormat)}.txt"),
            Layout = new CsvLayout()
            {
                Columns =
                {
                    new CsvColumn("Time", @"${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff}"),
                    new CsvColumn("Level", "${level}"),
                    new CsvColumn("Lessage", "${message}"),
                    new CsvColumn("Logger", "${logger}")
                }
            },
            ConcurrentWrites = true,
            KeepFileOpen = false,
            ArchiveFileName = Path.Combine(folderLog, fileName + ".{#}.txt"),
            ArchiveNumbering = ArchiveNumberingMode.Date,
            ArchiveDateFormat = dateTimeFormat,
            ArchiveEvery = FileArchivePeriod.Minute
        };

        // Console target
        var consoleTarget = new ConsoleTarget()
        {
            Name = "ConsoleTarget",
            Layout = @"${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss} ${logger} ${message}"
        };

        var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
        config.AddTarget(consoleTarget);
        config.AddTarget(fileTarget);

        // Define rules
        var rule1 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, consoleTarget);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(rule1);

        var rule2 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Info, fileTarget);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(rule2);

        // Apply
        _logFactory = new LogFactory(config);
    }
```

Please help me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using NLog 4.5 (or newer) then I would just do this:

```
        var fileTarget = new FileTarget
        {
            Name = "FileTarget",
            FileName = Path.Combine(folderLog, fileName + ".${date:format=" + dateTimeFormat + "}.txt"),
            Layout = new CsvLayout()
            {
                Columns = {
                new CsvColumn("Time", @"${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff}"),
                new CsvColumn("Level", "${level}"),
                new CsvColumn("Lessage", "${message}"),
                new CsvColumn("Logger", "${logger}")
                }
            },
            ConcurrentWrites = true,
            KeepFileOpen = false,
        };
```

Because you have added the date to the `FileName`, then you don't need to configure any archive options, as it happens automatically (Archive options are only needed if writing to a static-filename. Ex `log.txt`)

Consider changing to `ConcurrentWrites=false` and `KeepFileOpen=true`. It will reduce the overhead of logging (Doesn't open and close the file for each write-operation).

If you want to have archive logic to create new file when reaching a certain size. Then you can activate `ArchiveAboveSize`:

```
        var fileTarget = new FileTarget
        {
            Name = "FileTarget",
            FileName = Path.Combine(folderLog, fileName + ".${date:format=" + dateTimeFormat + "}.txt"),
            ArchiveAboveSize = 2000000,
            ArchiveFileName = Path.Combine(folderLog, fileName + ".{#}.txt"),
            ArchiveNumbering = ArchiveNumberMode.DateAndSequence,
            ArchiveDateFormat = dateTimeFormat,
        };
```

Comment: @RoftKristensen, It's work perfect. But I have a problem that When I write log 14h -> 20h, only 3 file log of hour (18, 19, 20) is reamain, file log (14, 15, 16, 17) is deleted. It is bug of Nlog?

Comment: No idea why files are deleted. NLog only deletes files if you configure `maxArchiveFiles` . You can try and check the NLog https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Comment: I want check size of my file log. If size of file > 2MB, I will create a new file log (add character "_1", "_2", etc...) after name of file log. How to handler it in NLOg?

Comment: @BillNguyen Added example of how to use ArchiveAboveSize. But the documentation is always a good place to start: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/File-target

Comment: It's work, @RoftKristensen, you're master of Library NLOg, LOL :D